# Access specific nodes through torque in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, pbs, torque

I would like to run a parallel job in Matlab, but ask for specific nodes to run into. I use torque to connect to the cluster.

I tried in 
ADDITIONAL TORQUE PROFILES
Resourse list parameter:

```
-l nodes=nod1+nod2+nod3
```

To connect to the specific three nodes: nod1 and nod2 and nod3 (node names).

However this does not work when I try to validate.

Comment: What happens that doesn't work? Is there an error message?

Comment: The validation stops at 3rd step, with error:SPMD Job test failed

Comment: I'm looking for an error message from Torque. I'm not familiar with your validation process.